# Postman showing 204 No Content instead of Response body

Tags: node.js, api, postman, response

In my `nodejs` application, I've a get API that takes some data, do some calculation on it, insert data in database andreturns calculated value back to user. I'm testing this API from `postman`, it is working perfectly fine i.e. Data inserted successfully in database. But it does not return `responseBody`, instead I'm getting `204 no Content` in postman.

Here is what my final response looks like

```
{"headers":{"authorization":"Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9","user-agent":"PostmanRuntime/7.26.8","accept":"*/*","postman-token":"cf8ae1e4-e5db-46d5-bc86-0bf22c0a2cd3","host":"localhost:9988","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, br","connection":"keep-alive","method":"GET","client":"PostmanRuntime/7.26.8","responseTime":"803.764ms"},"url":"/app/calculateData/bfa8f77a13a?currentdata=-5&frequency=10","requestBody":{},"responseBody":{"result":"5"}}
```

I don't know what I am missing here. here is my API call structure..

**Router file:**

```
    app.get('/app/calculateData/:userId', (req, res, next) => { return controllers.appController.calculateData(req, res, next);});
```

**Controller:**

```
calculateData(req, res, next) {

    res.responseGenerator = {};
    res.responseGenerator.responseCode = 204;

    let params = Object.assign({}, req.params, req.query )


    this.appService.calculateData(params, (err, myResult) => {

        res.responseGenerator.result = myResult;
        if (err) return next(err);
        return next();
    });
    
}
```

**Service:**

```
calculateData(params, callback) {
    let self = this;
    let dbContext = self.mysqlResource.getContext();
    let appSqlDao = new appSqlDao(dbContext)

    return appSqlDao.calculateData( params, (err, res) => {
        dbContext.release()
                if (err){
               return callback(err)
        }
         
        let objResult = {}
        objResult.result = res.result.toString()
        return callback( null, objResult )
            })        
    }
```

**And here is DAO File:**

```
calculateData(filters, callback) {

    let targetHcp = null
    let varcharUserId = this.dbContext.escape(filters.userId)
    
    let query = `CALL db.calculateData(${varcharUserId})`
    return this.dbContext.runQuery(query, (err, res) => {

    if (err) {
            err.status = 111;
            err.code = 11111;
            err.message = 'Internal database error';
            
        }
        if (res.length) {
            calValue = res[0][0]
        }
        return callback(err, calValue)
    })
}
```

> I don't know what I am missing here. Any kind of help will be
> appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

res.responseGenerator.responseCode = 204 -- Here is your culprit.

Comment: ohh my bad... Thank you